# Bootstrap 2.x button not center-aligned in dialog box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know similar questions have been asked earlier, but I have tried them and they aren't working. I have a dialog box, with some text and a button, which I need to position in the center of the box. My HTML is given below:

```
<div id='step3' class='item'>
    <div class='row span9'>
        <div class="text center"><button id='loginButton' class='btn btn-success' onClick='window.location.reload()'>Login again</button></div>
        <small>using your new credentials.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried placing the button inside a div and used `<div style="text-align:center">` but it didn't work. Does anyone know how I could place the button in the center, preferably without adding an external CSS class?

Answer (score 0):

Your `class="text center"` should be `class="text-center"`, and you also don't need the `row` tag (it breaks the responsiveness).

```
<div id="step3" class="item">
<div class="span12">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button id="loginButton" class="btn btn-success" onClick="window.location.reload()">Login again</button>
        <br> <small>using your new credentials.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you have single quotes `''` on most of your markup. Keep in mind this is with an old version of Bootstrap so depending on how wide the viewport is it might not be perfectly center.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. The button is moved, but now it goes to the extreme right of the dialog (part of it outside). It's not being placed exactly in the centre.

Comment: I'll try fixing it with span3 or something like that.